# Running Lucid (10.04) in virtualbox in 2020 - dependencies

Tags: dependencies, 10.04

Working from home during lockdown, I seem to need to use the Linux version of some proprietary software (Bruker OPUS). It's the only software that will read the proprietary file format. I don't have a Windows machine or an off-site licence, but the Linux binaries are a free download. The software was last updated nearly 10 years ago and  apparently doesn't run under 12.04 or later.

I've installed Lucid in a virtual machine.  While I can't get the guest extensions to install I can make ISOs to transfer stuff onto it. However OPUS needs `libboost` and probably other things (this seems to be one of several reasons it won't install on a newer OS) and the repository for Lucid no longer exists on `archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/`.

So how can I satisfy dependencies for an OS so old the repositories aren't there any more?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi That didn't come up in my searches though I thought there should be something.  After a quick browse I've flagged my own question as a dupe

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to have correct repositories:

- `archive.ubuntu.com` → `old-releases.ubuntu.com`
- `security.ubuntu.com` → `old-releases.ubuntu.com`

And then use `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` with `sudo apt-get install something` as usual.